# Capacitor startActivityForResult() trigger callback function on second activity start

Tags: android, capacitor

In my app I had to write plugin where I call Activity. This Activity return results which has to be sent back to Ionic app by `notifyListeners` method.

When I start `bridgeMethod` on first time `callbackFunction` doesn't start, but when I call this method again - everything works.

This is how I'm starting my activity and configure callback function.

```java
    @PluginMethod
    public void bridgeMethod (PluginCall aPluginCall) {
        // Other logic removed for clarity
        startSession(final PluginCall aCall);
    }

    private void startSession(final PluginCall aCall) {
        Intent myChildView = new Intent(getContext(), MyChildView.class);
        ChildViewSettings childViewSettings = mapSettings(aCall);
        scanView.putExtra("settings", childViewSettings);
        bridge.saveCall(aCall);
        startActivityForResult(aCall, childViewSettings, "callbackFunciton");
    }
```

and this is callback function

```java
    @ActivityCallback
    private void callbackFunciton(PluginCall call, ActivityResult result) {
        if (call == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            assert result.getData() != null;
            // processing callback data        
        }
    }
```

I found some information about saving plugin call in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050657/pass-onactivityresult-data-back-to-hybrid-app-from-capacitor) but not sure if I `saveCall` properly.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I want to trigger callback function on every time when Activity started with `startActivityForResult` will finish.